# Restricting Parent Issue status based on sub-task status

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

> Is there a FREE way in JIRA to require that a parent issue can't be
>   advanced to a state until the children (sub-tasks) are advanced to an
>   equal or greater state?

FOR EXAMPLE: Suppose an issue has 4 sub-tasks: 3 in `PROD` state and 1 sub-task is in `UAT` state. I shouldn't be able to advance the main issue to `PROD` until that 1 sub-task is advanced to `PROD` first so all my sub-tasks are in `PROD` state. Same thing with `CLOSING` an issue when sub-tasks are `OPEN`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such specific post function out of the box from Jira but you can surely write your own plugin or Groovy script(this needs script runner plugin) which can do this job.

Simple condition like, you cannot close parent issue unless sub tasks are closed can be achieved as simple as this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/preventing-issues-from-being-closed-while-their-sub-task-are-still-open-724928276.html

Other helpful discussions can be referred here:

1. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/142131/parent-issue-needs-to-close-once-sub-task-are-closed
2. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/262497/close-subtask-when-parent-is-closed
3. https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Post+Functions#PostFunctions-Autocloseallsubtasks

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, under the transition Conditions. Add a condition Called "Sub-Task Blocking Condition.

[image: List of various possible conditions]

Then, select the statuses the sub-task requires before the parent tasks can move forward. You can select more than one, so select the statuses that are equal to or greater state. Heads up though: the selection page shows all existing statuses, not just the statuses used for that workflow.

Do this for each step you want restricted.